# How to make a pop up window while the app icon clicked instead of opening Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, popup

I want make an app by which I want to open it in small screen/view like popup window instead of Full Screen Activity.
Suppose,when a user click on the application icon in his device it will show a popup window (contains various buttons/options) instead of opening any full screen activity!
Is there any way ? If possible then, How can I proceed ?
Wishing code snapshots or any demo or necessary suggestions regarding this problem!

Comment: as far as i know i don't think what you're trying to do is possible, i've only heard about creating popups in the activities themselves not making the whole app appear like a pop up, someone should correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a popup, but you can use the Dialog theme and make your Activity appear like a dialog box by using:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```